# SOAPClient Error when in PHP Magento 2 Adminhtml

Tags: php, magento, soap, magento2

I am a beginner about use Soap Call in PHP.

I want to use soap call in Magento 2. But I have a problem.

When I use soap call in frontend , its OK.

When I use soap Call in backend, its error:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (SoapFault): SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from '_THE URL_' : complex type 'handleType', attribute 'base': The QName value 'layoutType' does not resolve to a(n) simple type definition.
SoapClient->SoapClient()
```

My code:

```
$this->client = new \SoapClient($this->wsdlUrl, ["trace" => true,]);
$this->client->__setLocation($this->gatewayEndpointUrl);
```

Comment: The solution is done !. I simply replace \SoapClient by \Zend_Soap_Client. It can working well in magento 2 backend.